# Solspace Calendar ICS not working on Android

Tags: solspace-calendar

For some reason I'm running into an issue with adding ICS calendar's to android devices. Three different phones were used and in every case the file can't be added. Two of them say it's not sure what file it is and asks what to do, the other says download failed. It is working on iOS devices and computers.

This is [a link](http://www.calvarynaperville.org/events/ical/6152) to one of the generated ICS.

This is what I'm using to generate the individual event ICS files:

```
{exp:calendar:icalendar event_id="{segment_3}" dynamic="off"}{/exp:calendar:icalendar}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried opening another .ics file coming from another, non-Calendar, source (eg. from iCal)? Were you able to open this file? In my tests, Android wasn't able to open the file.

Comment: Wow, this really doesn't work on Android. Had no idea they had this large of a bug [for as long](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1257&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). Based on a few things I've read it might be possible to get VCS files to work. Gonna do a few tests to see if that's true.